# Push Multi line string to excel using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to add a multiline string to excelsheet to a particular row  and column. I intend to do something like we do to a cell

```
worksheet.cell('A1').style.alignment.wrap_text = True
```

But unable to figure out how to do same when passing row no. and col. no.

Below code works except for the 4th line.Can you suggest what is the correct method to achieve the same?

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('template.xlsx')    
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
sheet.cell(row=row_no, column=8).style.alignment.wrap_text = True
sheet.cell(row=row_no, column=8).value = config
xfile.save('template.xlsx')
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? You should provide a complete error message. Though I think you should also check that the version of the documentation you're using matches the version of the library.

Comment: i found the solution on my own...the fourth line needs to be replaced withsheet.cell(row=row_no, column=8).alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works successfully:

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('template.xlsx')    
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
sheet.cell(row=row_no, column=8).style.alignment.wrap_text = True
sheet.cell(row=row_no, column=8).alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)
xfile.save('template.xlsx')
```

Comment: There is no need to answer your own question. Just correct it and explain the change (you were using the wrong documentation).

Comment: sir,why at all does that option to answer your own que exists then?i just used the functionality provided

Comment: @CharlieClark There is nothing wrong with answering  one's own questions. It's actually encouraged if you read through the help center.

Comment: for your recent question, give a try to `print re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), m.group()), s)` where d is the dict having mapping info and s is the input string